# Scroll to load more content inside div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have seen many answers related to these but none suited my case. I have the following script to auto-load files on scroll.

**My Problem:**

- The auto-loading of the files work in FF, Edge, Chrome(Desktop) but not in chrome(android). The **version of Chrome on Android** is **54.0.2840.85** and **version of android** is **6.0.1**.
- Another problem is that on EDGE mobile(on Lumia device running windows 10) it works properly but if I hide the navigation bar it doesnt work.

**JS**

```
// Auto-loading of older files
    var track_page = 1;
    var isAllDone = false;
    $('#list-content').on('scroll', function () {
       if(isAllDone) return;

       if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
           track_page++;
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "./generate_list.php",
               data: 'page='+track_page,
               beforeSend: function() {
                   $('#loadMore').show();
               },
               success: function (response) {
                   var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                   var arr = obj.items;
                   if (arr.length == 0) {
                       $('#loadMore').html("That's all folks!").show();
                       isAllDone = true;
                   }
                   else {
                       $('#loadMore').hide();

                       $(arr).each(function (i, val) {
                          li = $(val);
                          filelist.append(li);
                          li.delay(400 * i).slideDown(400);
                       });
                   }
               }
           });
       }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="list-content">
    <ul id="file_list">
    </ul>
    <div id="loadMore"><img src="images/loader.gif"></div>
</div>
```